# Java 8 SSL failure on initial handshake

Tags: java, ssl, java-8

A connection which has previously worked fine now causes handshake failure at the initial handshake. I.e. the SSL log shows a ClientHello, and then

> Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

before getting a ServerHello. I have checked with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=snl.no and there should not be a problem with cipher suites or TLS version.

Relevant (?) portion of the SSL log:

```
javax.net.ssl|FINE|16 61|New I/O worker #36|2023-09-11 14:54:50.305 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:505|WRITE: TLS13 handshake, length = 377
javax.net.ssl|FINE|16 61|New I/O worker #36|2023-09-11 14:54:50.306 CEST|SSLEngineOutputRecord.java:523|Raw write (
  0000: 16 03 03 01 79 01 00 01   75 03 03 0E 38 E9 53 F4  ....y...u...8.S.
  0010: 6F CA B9 08 6E B6 FD C2   56 8F C3 90 7C 39 B3 62  o...n...V....9.b
  0020: 49 97 06 6D 6C 0B 7A AD   87 63 95 20 0F 60 8F 82  I..ml.z..c. .`..
  0030: E3 4A F3 25 B9 B1 DD A0   27 E6 94 6F 70 3F 41 39  .J.%....'..op?A9
  0040: FA 10 E5 45 F0 15 98 6D   05 2C 79 8B 00 5A 13 02  ...E...m.,y..Z..
  0050: 13 01 C0 2C C0 2B C0 30   C0 2F 00 9F 00 A3 00 9E  ...,.+.0./......
  0060: 00 A2 C0 24 C0 28 C0 23   C0 27 00 6B 00 6A 00 67  ...$.(.#.'.k.j.g
  0070: 00 40 C0 2E C0 32 C0 2D   C0 31 C0 26 C0 2A C0 25  .@...2.-.1.&.*.%
  0080: C0 29 C0 0A C0 14 C0 09   C0 13 00 39 00 38 00 33  .).........9.8.3
  0090: 00 32 C0 05 C0 0F C0 04   C0 0E 00 9D 00 9C 00 3D  .2.............=
  00A0: 00 3C 00 35 00 2F 00 FF   01 00 00 D2 00 0A 00 12  .<.5./..........
  00B0: 00 10 00 17 00 18 00 19   01 00 01 01 01 02 01 03  ................
  00C0: 01 04 00 0B 00 02 01 00   00 0D 00 28 00 26 04 03  ...........(.&..
  00D0: 05 03 06 03 08 04 08 05   08 06 08 09 08 0A 08 0B  ................
  00E0: 04 01 05 01 06 01 04 02   03 03 03 01 03 02 02 03  ................
  00F0: 02 01 02 02 00 32 00 28   00 26 04 03 05 03 06 03  .....2.(.&......
  0100: 08 04 08 05 08 06 08 09   08 0A 08 0B 04 01 05 01  ................
  0110: 06 01 04 02 03 03 03 01   03 02 02 03 02 01 02 02  ................
  0120: 00 17 00 00 00 2B 00 05   04 03 04 03 03 00 2D 00  .....+........-.
  0130: 02 01 01 00 33 00 47 00   45 00 17 00 41 04 F7 1B  ....3.G.E...A...
  0140: 8D 37 18 D5 E9 DD 4F 85   85 BD FF DF ED 3B 94 87  .7....O......;..
  0150: BF 4B 79 D3 49 8A B3 11   BC 98 B9 53 1E 1B B6 28  .Ky.I......S...(
  0160: EF 7E 16 0D 73 CA E9 A4   51 95 CE C7 D0 80 18 8C  ....s...Q.......
  0170: 7B C7 13 74 F1 29 D7 93   E6 1E BE 39 10 6C        ...t.).....9.l
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|16 61|New I/O worker #36|2023-09-11 14:54:50.333 CEST|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:177|Raw read (
  0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 28                               ......(
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|16 61|New I/O worker #36|2023-09-11 14:54:50.334 CEST|SSLEngineInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1 alert, length = 2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|16 61|New I/O worker #36|2023-09-11 14:54:50.334 CEST|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
```

Any ideas what is wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Do you use openjdk oder the jdk from Oracle?

Comment: Looks like you use `TLS13` and server `TLS1`. Can it be, that servierside the 1.3 is not supported?

Comment: OpenJDK
The server supports TLSv1.3 according to SSL Server Test (I have also tried forcing TLSv1.2 but that makes no difference).

Comment: Any information server side?

Comment: Well, what SSLlabs tell: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=snl.no
I'm not familiar enough with this to make out the nuances, but nothing looks strange.

Comment: As ssllabs says **"This site works only in browsers with SNI support."** where 'browser' really means 'client', and your code is sending ClientHello without SNI. Some older versions of Java/JSSE had bugs about SNI, but any update that supports TLS1.3 -- i.e. 8u261 up -- should support SNI UNLESS you use an API that doesn't pass the servername (like creating a TCP `Socket` and overlaying the `SSLSocket` on it) or you set sysprop `jsse.enableSNIextension=false` -- did you do either of those?

Comment: I definitely don't set jsse.enableSNIextension=false, cannot say about the server name, as I don't handle the lower level details myself, using the HTTP client of (an old version of) Play!Framework. But, this is something to dig further into. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, switching to another HTTP client inplementation (Apache HTTP) works.